# Highcharts plugin/extension that runs after the chart has loaded

Tags: javascript, events, highcharts

I'm trying to move some of my custom Highcharts code that currently resides inside `events.load` into a [Highcharts extension](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) so it's more modular and clean.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HA5xE/95/) of what I have right now.

As you can tell from the code, I change some value label properties when the chart has fully rendered, by calling `chart.events.load`.

So from my understanding, using `H.wrap` would allow me to override an existing prototype function and let me add code before or after it.

And this is where I am sort of confused:

1. Should I perform my value label hiding procedure within an existing prototype?
2. How can I convert the `chart.events.load` code into an extension that (also) gets called after a chart is loaded?

I think I can use

```
H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'onload', function (p) { ... }
```

But I am not entirely sure

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `wrapp` unless I have to, e.g. when I would need to control when the wrapped function is called.

Other ways:

1. Add a function as a callback to `Chart.prototype`

   ```
   Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
     console.log('callback')
   })
   ```
2. Add chart's `load` event

   ```
   Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Chart, 'load', function () {
     console.log('load event')
   })
   ```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/kyfbwjke/

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'onload', function (p) { ... }
```

Is the same as `charts.events.load`